# notifyDataSetChanged() makes the list refresh and scroll jumps back to the top of list

Tags: android, listview, notifydatasetchanged

This is the main class.  When I scroll down for more data and call the adapter, the list refreshes and scrolling jumps back to the top of list. I tried this for two days, but the issue remains.

I want the same position of list when scrolling down position.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    ArrayList<String> home_youmay_filepath = new ArrayList<String>();


    ListView listViewyoumay;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);

        listViewyoumay = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvItems);
        // Attach the listener to the AdapterView onCreate
        listViewyoumay.setOnScrollListener(new EndlessScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLoadMore(int page, int totalItemsCount) {
                // Triggered only when new data needs to be appended to the list
                // Add whatever code is needed to append new items to your AdapterView
                youmaylike(page);

                // or customLoadMoreDataFromApi(totalItemsCount);
                return true; // ONLY if more data is actually being loaded; false otherwise.

            }
        });

        youmaylike(1);


    }

    private void showpDialog() {
        if (!pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.show();
    }

    private void hidepDialog() {
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
    }

    private void youmaylike(int a) {

        showpDialog();

        Log.d("Starta", "Start" + a);

        String url = "http://v2.picsdream.com/api/v1/galleries/abstract?page=" + a;


        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
                url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        Log.d("cmsResponce", response.toString());

                        try {


                            JSONObject cards = response.getJSONObject("cards");


                            JSONArray data = cards.getJSONArray("data");

                            for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {

                                JSONObject person = (JSONObject) data
            .get(i);


                                String filepath = person.getString("filepath");


                                home_youmay_filepath.add(filepath);


                            }

                            PhotofargmentAdapteryoumay adapter3 = new PhotofargmentAdapteryoumay(MainActivity.this, home_youmay_filepath);
                            listViewyoumay.setAdapter(adapter3);
                            adapter3.notifyDataSetChanged();


                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                        hidepDialog();
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        VolleyLog.d("LoginError", "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        // hide the progress dialog
                        hidepDialog();
                    }
                });

        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq);
    }


    public class PhotofargmentAdapteryoumay extends BaseAdapter {


        ArrayList<String> home_youmay_filepath = new ArrayList<String>();



        private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
        Context context;

        public PhotofargmentAdapteryoumay(Context Time_table, ArrayList<String> home_youmay_filepath) {

            this.context = Time_table;

            this.home_youmay_filepath = home_youmay_filepath;


            layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(Time_table);

        }


        @Override
        public int getCount() {

            return home_youmay_filepath.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder holder;
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.photoadapter_layout, null);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                // holder.month = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvtext);
                holder.img = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_nature);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }
            // holder.month.setText(listData.get(position).getMonth());

            String image = home_youmay_filepath.get(position);


            Log.d("Image", image);


            try {


                Picasso.with(context)
                    .load(image).noFade()
                    .into(holder.img);

                //                ImageLoader imgLoader = new ImageLoader(HomeActivity.this);
                //
                //                imgLoader.DisplayImage(image, holder.img);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            return convertView;
        }

        class ViewHolder {
            //  TextView month;
            ImageView img;
        }
    }


    public abstract class EndlessScrollListener implements AbsListView.OnScrollListener {
        // The minimum number of items to have below your current scroll position
        // before loading more.
        private int visibleThreshold = 50;
        // The current offset index of data you have loaded
        private int currentPage = 1;
        // The total number of items in the dataset after the last load
        private int previousTotalItemCount = 50;
        // True if we are still waiting for the last set of data to load.
        private boolean loading = true;
        // Sets the starting page index
        private int startingPageIndex = 1;

        public EndlessScrollListener() {
        }

        public EndlessScrollListener(int visibleThreshold) {
            this.visibleThreshold = visibleThreshold;
        }

        public EndlessScrollListener(int visibleThreshold, int startPage) {
            this.visibleThreshold = visibleThreshold;
            //            this.startingPageIndex = startPage;
            this.currentPage = startPage;
        }


        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
            // If the total item count is zero and the previous isn't, assume the
            // list is invalidated and should be reset back to initial state


            if (totalItemCount < previousTotalItemCount) {
                this.currentPage = this.startingPageIndex;
                this.previousTotalItemCount = totalItemCount;
                if (totalItemCount == 0) {
                    this.loading = true;
                }
            }


            // If it's still loading, we check to see if the dataset count has
            // changed, if so we conclude it has finished loading and update the current page
            // number and total item count.
            if (loading && (totalItemCount > previousTotalItemCount)) {
                loading = false;
                previousTotalItemCount = totalItemCount;
                currentPage++;
            }

            // If it isn't currently loading, we check to see if we have breached
            // the visibleThreshold and need to reload more data.
            // If we do need to reload some more data, we execute onLoadMore to fetch the data.
            if (!loading && (firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount + visibleThreshold) >= totalItemCount) {
                loading = onLoadMore(currentPage + 1, totalItemCount);
            }
        }

        // Defines the process for actually loading more data based on page
        // Returns true if more data is being loaded; returns false if there is no more data to load.
        public abstract boolean onLoadMore(int page, int totalItemsCount);

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
            // Don't take any action on changed
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
PhotofargmentAdapteryoumay adapter3 = new PhotofargmentAdapteryoumay(MainActivity.this, home_youmay_filepath);
                            listViewyoumay.setAdapter(adapter3);
```

Remove this lines

Comment: but if i remove these lines , the data will not show on listview...  where do i call the adapter class than and set data on listview?    plz some tips for this...

Comment: Not Three lines Only remove above two lines   adapter3.notifyDataSetChanged();
Keep this line as it is

Comment: sorry for my english

Comment: Working or not?

Comment: @MohitTrivedi can you please check this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58849910/how-to-stop-refreshing-recyclerview-data-scroll-to-top-position-android